# How to allow a user to enter in a year number and pull the average, min, and max life expectancy from that list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

So for an assignment I have to do I have to allow the user to enter a year and python will go through the entire .csv file (which I'll link in case it allows people to help a little bit better), find all the countries life expectancy's during that year, then add them all up and display the average, the min, and the max. I've been trying different things at my computer but for the life of me I can not figure out how to do this, it just hurts my head to even think about. If anybody could offer help I'd be extremely grateful. Below is the code I've got so far:

```
filename = 'Life_expectancy.csv'
rows = []
with open(filename) as le_file: 
    next(le_file) 
    for line in le_file: 
 
        line = line.strip().split(",") 
        rows.append(line)

ages = [row[3] for row in rows]
min_age_idx = ages.index(min(ages))
max_age_idx = ages.index(max(ages))


details = rows[min_age_idx]
detailsElectricBoogaloo = rows[max_age_idx]
print('Name: {}, Code: {}, Year: {}, Life Expectancy: {}'.format(details[0], details[1], details[2], details[3]))
print('Name: {}, Code: {}, Year: {}, Life Expectancy:{}'.format(detailsElectricBoogaloo[0], detailsElectricBoogaloo[1], detailsElectricBoogaloo[2], detailsElectricBoogaloo[3]))
```

Also I discovered I can't link a file so I'll copy and paste a portion of the csv data

```
Entity,Code,Year,Life expectancy (years)
Afghanistan,AFG,1950,27.638
Afghanistan,AFG,1951,27.878
Afghanistan,AFG,1952,28.361
Afghanistan,AFG,1953,28.852
Afghanistan,AFG,1954,29.35
Afghanistan,AFG,1955,29.854
Albania,ALB,1950,54.191
Albania,ALB,1951,54.399
Albania,ALB,1952,54.875
Albania,ALB,1953,55.468
Albania,ALB,1954,56.18
Albania,ALB,1955,57.007
Algeria,DZA,1950,42.087
Algeria,DZA,1951,42.282
Algeria,DZA,1952,42.677
Algeria,DZA,1953,43.081
Algeria,DZA,1954,43.494
Algeria,DZA,1955,43.916
```

This list goes on like this for every country in the world with this data public and goes between 1950 to 2019 with some being around 1923 to 2019 and around that time period. I can't even think about how to start this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem. - `If anybody could offer help ` -[“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use built-in module `statistics`, there's function [`mean`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean). For finding minimum, maximum, you can use `min()/max()` functions.

For example:

```
import csv
from statistics import mean

data = []
with open('data.csv', 'r', newline='') as f_in:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    next(csv_reader)  # skip headers
    for row in csv_reader:
        data.append(row)

year = input('Please enter the year: ')

average = mean(float(d[3]) for d in data if d[2] == year)
min_ = min((d for d in data if d[2] == year), key=lambda k: float(k[3]))
max_ = max((d for d in data if d[2] == year), key=lambda k: float(k[3]))

print('Statistics for year:', year)
print('-' * 80)
print('Average {:.2f}'.format(average))
print('Min :', min_)
print('Max :', max_)
```

Prints (for example):

```
Please enter the year: 1951
Statistics for year: 1951
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Average 41.52
Min : ['Afghanistan', 'AFG', '1951', '27.878']
Max : ['Albania', 'ALB', '1951', '54.399']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check out pandas DataFrame, with the DataFrame you can easily read in the csv and afterwards filter for the year you need

Comment: That is not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using the csv built in module to parse your csv, something like

```
import csv

with open('Life_expectancy.csv', 'r') as file_handler:
    data = [row for row in csv.reader(file_handler)]
```

but in terms of how to filter it, you can do that a number of ways:

for loop

```
results = []

for row in data:

    if row[2] == 'input_year':  # row[2] = third row, zero indexed

        results.append(row)

print(results)
```

filter

```
results = [row for row in filter(lambda x: x[2] == 'input_year', data)]
print(results)
```

list comprehension

```
results = [row for row in data if row[2] == 'input_year']
print(results)
```

then there is the averaging process:

```
total_life_expectancy = sum([row[3] for row in results])
average_life_expectancy = total_life_expectancy / len(total_life_expectancy)
```

you could potentially even combine these into one step with a combination of the above, but I recommend doing things in steps so that you can more easily keep track of the process.

Answer (score -1):

I've renamed the CSV file `data.csv`, and I've hardcoded the `year`, but you get the idea:

```
def main():
    import csv
    import statistics

    with open("data.csv") as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        year = "1955"
        year_ages = list(map(lambda d: float(d["Life expectancy (years)"]), filter(lambda d: d["Year"] == year, reader)))

    minimum = min(year_ages)
    maximum = max(year_ages)
    average = statistics.mean(year_ages)

    print(year.center(32, "-"))
    print(f"The minimum life expectancy was {minimum:.2f} years.")
    print(f"The maximum life expectancy was {maximum:.2f} years.")
    print(f"The average life expectancy was {average:.2f} years.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
--------------1955--------------
The minimum life expectancy was 29.85 years.
The maximum life expectancy was 57.01 years.
The average life expectancy was 43.59 years.
>>>
```